# is there a way to loop through images inside assets/images folder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some images inside my assets/images folder, and I want to loop through them and upload them to Firebase storage.
is there a way to do that??
Thanks.

Comment: Search for similar questions about getting a directory of all assets.